# How to calculate an estimate monthly bill of using azure resources

Tags: azure, billing

I am currently using the 30 days `free subscription` on `azure`. I have a `python web app` and `azure cosmos mongodb`. My free subscrption is about to end and I am planning to upgrade it. But I am not aware of how much monthly bill will be.?

Is there any way I can get approx idea of monthly bill on azure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cost Management service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cost-management/) to determine your monthly cost. Also if you are aware of the resources you will be using calculate the estimation using the [Azure calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)